# Driver menu not visible in Visual Studio 11

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a metadata package with the authering wizard in windows 8 dev preview.

As instructed in [Installing the Device Metadata Authoring Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh454221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx),  I have installed the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview and then the WDK 7.1.0.

But still cannot locate the Driver menu in the visual studio.

I am totally new to the Windows 8. Please help on the issue

Note:The documents say "install and launch the wdk". How do you launch the wdk in windows8

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the newer [WDK 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852362.aspx) in order to get the DRIVER menu in Visual Studio 2012.